# How to disable menu strip submenus

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to disable a menu item's sub child dynamically. Here in menu bar if I clcik Run At startup, Disable Startup option should be disabled  how to achieve this. I have attached the snapshot for reference

```
// Run At Startup
 private void runAtStartupToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   rkApp.SetValue("TimeCalculation", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath.ToString() + "\"");
   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
   menuStrip1.Items["disableStartupToolStripMenuItem"].Enabled = false;

 }

 //Disable Startup
 private void disableStartupToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   rkApp.DeleteValue("TimeCalculation", false);
   menuStrip1.Items["runAtStartupToolStripMenuItem"].Enabled = false;
 }
```

**SnapShot:**

[image]

Comment: What's `Environment.GetFolderPath` for? You don't use its return value.

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag:

```
private bool flag = true;

private void runAtStartupToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
    flag = true;
}

private void disableStartupToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
    flag = false;
}
```

Then use the `DropDownOpening` event to enable/disable the items.

```
private void bToolStripMenuItem_DropDownOpening(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    runAtStartupToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = !flag;
    disableStartupToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = flag;
}
```

If you want to hide the item use `Available`:

```
    runAtStartupToolStripMenuItem.Available= !flag;
    disableStartupToolStripMenuItem.Available= flag;
```

Comment: What's the point in keeping another flag? You already have one, the `Checked` state of the "Run At Startup" menu item. Just use that one!

Comment: Also, are you sure that there is an `Available` property? I believe you may be thinking of `Visible`.

Comment: @CodyGray: 1) That's right. But I usually use separate flags, so the functionality is not bound to the UI. This makes it possible to move the functionality elsewhere, while my UI is still working.   2) There IS a `Available` i used it myself.